# How to print to terminal in a function but not return it as return value?

Tags: bash

How to write to terminal for logging purposes within a function and not have that also as part of the function's return value?

This is my sample script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

my_fun() {
  echo "this is for logging purposes"
  retVal="Return only this"
  echo "$retVal"
}

returnedValue=$(my_fun)
if [ "Return only this" = "$returnedValue" ]; then
  echo "Good return"
else
  echo "Bad return"
fi
```

It outputs `Bad return` and does not print to terminal `this is for logging purposes`. How to return only `Return only this` without `this is for logging purposes` (because I want it to go to terminal)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect the output to standard error instead:

```
echo "this is for logging purposes" >&2
```

It would go to the terminal unless the standard error was redirected somewhere else.

Comment: this does the job, thanks @choroba!
I ended up creating a function which gets called from other functions when I want to "echo" something: `log() { echo "INFO LOG: $1" >&2 }`